# AWS IAM Policy to prevent accidental API Gateway delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm looking for a way to prevent accidental deletion of an API Gateway. However I can't find an example of an IAM policy to do so.

I'm currently at:

```json
{
            "Sid": "DenyDeleteAPIGateway",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:DELETE"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/apis/*"
            ]
        }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
My goal is simply to prevent actual API Gateway deletion, **not block all actions** on the actual AWG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct action, but you need to limit the resource. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonapigatewaymanagement.html

Something like:

```
{
        "Sid": "DenyDeleteAPIGateway",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "apigateway:DELETE"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis/*"
        ]
}
```

should do it. [API Gateway V1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonapigatewaymanagement.html) uses `/restapis` and [API Gateway V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonapigatewaymanagementv2.html) uses `/apis`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that `/apis` and `/restapis` can be used both. It's about AGW Managment and AGW Managment V2. Do you have any info on where to use V1 or V2?

Comment: Yes, `/restapis` is for V1 and `/apis` is for V2 - edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: Tested... and it works. Strangely though, there's no error message when you try to delete the Rest API. 
It's just... not deleted actually